# nginx docker alpine envsubst doesn't work when there's a command in docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'd like to use envsubst with nginx docker alpine. [Documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration-new-in-119):

> Using environment variables in nginx configuration (new in 1.19)
>
> Out-of-the-box, nginx doesn't support environment variables inside
> most configuration blocks. But this image has a function, which will
> extract environment variables before nginx starts.
>
> Here is an example using docker-compose.yml:
>
> web:   image: nginx   volumes:
>
> - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates   ports:
> - "8080:80"   environment:
> - NGINX_HOST=foobar.com
> - NGINX_PORT=80
>
> By default, this function reads template files in
> /etc/nginx/templates/*.template and outputs the result of executing
> envsubst to /etc/nginx/conf.d.

I have a nginx container service of the form:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      #- ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    env_file: .env
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
```

When I run this service, envsubst does not work. However, if I remove the `command:` in docker-compose, it does work.

I tried copying the command to a .sh file and moving it inside of the container at `/docker-entrypoint.d/mycommand.sh`. There are several other .sh files in here by default which are run before nginx is loaded:

```
ls -l docker-entrypoint.d
total 16
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root          1961 May 25 15:44 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root          1037 May 25 15:44 20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
-rwxrwxr-x    1 root     root          4613 May 25 15:44 30-tune-worker-processes.sh
```

I added `mycommand.sh` in there too using a volume. Here's what mycommand.sh looks like:

```
#! /bin/bash

# reload nginx config every 60 seconds in case certs get updated
while :; do
  sleep 60
  echo reloading
  nginx -s reload
done
```

However, when I add this script to `/docker-entrypoint.d` directory, nginx never seems to start.

How can I run my command AND make use of envsubst using nginx alpine per the documentation?

I'd prefer to be able to go this route as opposed to e.g. using a new nginx container with a shared volume to get the same result. Adding a .sh script to `docker-entrypoint.d` 'feels' like the 'right' way and would result in a more minimalist docker-compose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the command doesn't work because the `/docker-entrypoint.sh` contains:

```
if [ "$1" = "nginx" -o "$1" = "nginx-debug" ]; then
...
```

And when you change the command, `$1` becomes `/bin/sh`.

The scripts in `/docker-entrypoint.d` need to run and exit before the `docker-entrypoint.sh` gets to the end where it runs the command (by default, starting nginx). You can put that while loop in the background to achieve this, just appending a `&` after the done:

```
#! /bin/bash

# reload nginx config every 60 seconds in case certs get updated
while :; do
  sleep 60
  echo reloading
  nginx -s reload
done &
```

Note that this is very much an anti-pattern with containers that typically only makes sense in a development environment. In production, you would redeploy a new container with the new configuration.